# Is there any difference between 65535 and 65535UL

Tags: c, literals

I'm about to change a

```
#define MAX_UINT16 65535
```

to a

```
#define MAX_UINT16 65535UL
```

in a large library project used on many platforms. Is there any construct that behaves differently (except for some warnings disappearing, that's why I want to change it) when using `unsigned long` literals instead of `int` literals?

(There is no bit-shifting with MAX_UINT16 obviously)

I'm thinking of constructs like

```
unsigned long ulvar = read_something_as_unsigned_long();
uint16 ui16var;
if (ulvar > MAX_UINT16) {
    display_error("Not in range\n");
    ui16var = MAX_UINT16;
} else {
    ui16var = ulvar;
}
```

**edit:** Of course, `L` is not needed, so does it behave different when using `65535U`instead of `65535`?

Comment: Better fix the the warnings separatly. Using the `L` suffix really is a bad idea, as `long` is always larger then 16bits.

Comment: `65535U` should do, why `65535UL`?

Comment: @alk? What do you mean? There is a warning if I assign `MAX_UINT16` to a `uint16`. I don't want to add casts in every assignment...

Comment: @legends2k: You're right. So does it behave differently with `65535U`? Edited.

Comment: Also UL means the value is stored in a long sized piece of memory rather than a int sized one.... (this will change from platform to platform).

Comment: @AnthonyLambert: So does this behave differently?

Comment: Do not change the question after people answered or commented on your question. This easily makes such comments/answers ununderstandable. Add edits as an update instead.

Comment: Look at integer promotion rules. And yes, some, depends on what you do with it.

Comment: An integer constant's type, when left unqualified, is the first type in which it can be represented correctly in ascending order. When you mention it as say `L` it'll automatically be taken as `long` and then converted into an `int` when you assign it a variable of type `int`. By leaving it as `65535u` you just say it's unsigned but not more, so that the conversion is avoided.

Comment: @alk: Edited again to make this history clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any construct that behaves differently (except for some warnings disappearing, that's why I want to change it) when using unsigned long literals instead of int literals?

Here's the relevant part in the C11 (draft) standard *6.3.1.3* (emphasis mine):

> 6.3.1.3  Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1. When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
> 2. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.
> 3. **Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.**

If there's a point in code where `65535U` is, inadvertently, assigned to a signed type variable which cannot hold the value completely then the final value is implementation-defined. So assigning `65535U` to `int16_t` produces `-1` with GCC and VC++ but this result is not guarenteed by the standard and depends on the compiler implementation. Also, both GCC (`-Wall`) and VC++ (`/W4`) doesn't warn this by default; passing `-pedantic` does the trick in GCC.

That said this issue should be there even if it was continuing to be `65535` since it's larger than the maximum positive value holdable by a 16-bit signed 2's complement type. So my recommendation would be to go ahead and change it. Once done, enable the maximum warning level and build the project to verify this.